# ckeditor 'paste from Word': retain font color if not black

Tags: ckeditor

I'd like to get rid of most font styles as I paste in from Word, but have a way to retain font colours if they aren't the default (black). This way, if the text in my Word doc has a line of red text, I won't lose that.

Config options for the PasteFromWord plugin include a way to retain Word's font styles as they are pasted in (pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = false), but this opens the gates to whole lot of font cruft. All I want to let through is any non-default font color.

Retaining font sizes can be largely dealt with in Word by using H1-H6 styles there, but I don't see how I could have a style in Word for red text and have that paste over to CKEditor. Any help or ideas appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little hack to preserve the color styles by modifying the Paste From Word plugin.

First, turn on the style filter in your ckeditor config:

```
config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = true;
```

Now, Under the "ckeditor/plugins/pastefromword" folder, open "default.js".

Find this code section (line 956 at the time of writing):

```
// Assume MS-Word mostly carry font related styles on <span>,
// adapting them to editor's convention.
if ( styleText ) {
    attrs.style = stylesFilter( [
        // Drop 'inline-height' style which make lines overlapping.
        [ 'line-height' ],
        [ ( /^font-family$/ ), null, !removeFontStyles ? styleMigrateFilter( config.font_style, 'family' ) : null ],
        [ ( /^font-size$/ ), null, !removeFontStyles ? styleMigrateFilter( config.fontSize_style, 'size' ) : null ],
        [ ( /^color$/ ), null, !removeFontStyles ? styleMigrateFilter( config.colorButton_foreStyle, 'color' ) : null ],
        [ ( /^background-color$/ ), null, !removeFontStyles ? styleMigrateFilter( config.colorButton_backStyle, 'color' ) : null ]
    ] )( styleText, element ) || '';
}
```

In the line that starts with `/^color$/` change `!removeFontStyles` to `removeFontStyles` so the new line is now:

```
[ ( /^color$/ ), null, removeFontStyles ? styleMigrateFilter( config.colorButton_foreStyle, 'color' ) : null ],
```

Clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's not in the file I have. I just downloaded the plugin the other day, too. What I do see is this: 
if (e = (b = a.attributes) && b.style) b.style = l([
        ["line-height"],
        [/^font-family$/, null, r ? null : n(d.font_style, "family")],
        [/^font-size$/, null, r ? null : n(d.fontSize_style, "size")],
        [/^color$/, null, r ? null : n(d.colorButton_foreStyle, "color")],
        [/^background-color$/, null, r ? null : n(d.colorButton_backStyle, "color")]
       ])(e, a) || "";

Comment: @lauren I downloaded the plug-in from [here](http://ckeditor.com/addon/pastefromword) and it isn't minified js like the version you get when downloading the full ckeditor package. Much easier to understand and modify ...

Comment: Ah, that's much easier to read, and it works for manually-applied styles. However, my Word doc uses Word Styles - is there a way to perhaps add a font color preserve to the white-list code in that file? (pref, only if not already black). There is something promising-looking in the black-list but it's a wee bit beyond me.

Comment: I'm going to accept your reply as it works for plain cases. I think my issue is bigger, getting CKE to acknowledge Word Styles.

Comment: I think allowing Word styles to pass through, and then accepting some of their properties while rejecting others, will require diving deep into the "clipboard" plugin which normally just filters them out completely, but I'm not sure how to actually do it.